# Force unique instance of Zathura pdf

Tags: arch-linux, antergos, zathura, atom-editor

I am working on a LaTeX document using Atom editor with the atom-latex package and wish to use Zathura PDF to preview my output. It works fine but whenever I build, it will open a new instance of the pdf file. If I use evince it simply refreshes the file and keeps the output only to one instance. I am on Antergos Linux (Arch Derivative).

Comment: https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/mopen is what I use for `mupdf`, it checks whether the process/filename is open or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file `/usr/local/bin/zathura.sh`, and fill it with this content :

```
#!/bin/bash
killall zathura 2>/dev/null
zathura
```

And make it executable with this command : `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/zathura.sh`.

Now go to your `atom-latex` settings in your atom editor (*edit -> preferences -> packages -> latex -> settings*) and change the value of `Opener` to `custom`, and put inside `Custom PDF Viewer Path` this line `/usr/local/bin/zathura.sh`.

Now each time you build, the previous instance of zathura will close, and a new instance will be opened with your new pdf file in it.

It's not a perfect approach, but it will do the trick until the devs of `atom-latex` will add the support to `zathura` (I just submitted an issue in github [here](https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex/issues/324)).

## Edit

The devs of `atom-latex` just accepted my request, and said that the support will be added in the next version, so you just have to wait a little bit. You can see the request here : https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex/issues/324.

If you have a github account, you can encourage the devs by giving a star to [`atom-latex`](https://github.com/thomasjo/atom-latex) project.

Comment: Just what I needed! They have upgraded the package to support Zathura. It works great!